# DJANGO - Is it possible to pass arguments to settings through manage.py?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is it possible to pass arguments to settings through manage.py?

I need to pass some arguments to start a server with environment setup.

And I think it would be interesting to pass arguments to the settings.

Would anyone have another idea?

Thank you very much.

```
#python manage.py runserver var=local
```

Comment: The standard solution is environment variables `VAR=local python manage.py runserver` and then `os.environ.get('VAR')`.

Comment: This is work. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I normally have project setting as folder and then have base, production and development files which reflect setting as per envrioment and then I runserver using like `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.development`

Comment: where is it possible to customize the development, is it a file?

Comment: yes, its file. so you have `setting` as a folder with `__init__.py` and then you have as many files you want and you can set variables in a file and run server against the specific setting.

Comment: I'm trying reproduce your deployment setup but doesn't understand exacly how it works, could you explain a bit more?
How I imagine:
`
settings_base.py
settings_dev.py
settings_prod.py
`
settings_dev.py:
`
from django.conf import settings_base # ?
# override ENV_VARS
`
Thanks!